Why does my code not work in Leet Code? btw my code works in VSC
my code:
s = '[}'
num = len(set(s))
if num%2 == 0: return 'false'
else: return 'true'


expecting false but i got true for some reason in Leet code. The set function works properly in Visual Studio Code but not in Leet code for some reason... is there any changes need to be done?

I get "SyntaxError: 'return' outside function".

The return keyword can only be used within a function.
